# Fitting a sine wave with Keras and PYMC3 yields unexpected results

Tags: neural-network, keras, theano, pymc, pymc3

I've been trying to fit a sine curve with a keras (theano backend) model using pymc3. I've been using this [http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2016/07/05/bayesian-deep-learning/] as a reference point.

A Keras implementation alone fit using optimization does a good job, however Hamiltonian Monte Carlo and Variational sampling from pymc3 is not fitting the data. The trace is stuck at where the prior is initiated. When I move the prior the posterior moves to the same spot. The posterior predictive of the bayesian model in cell 59 is barely getting the sine wave, whereas the non-bayesian fit model gets it near perfect in cell 63. I created a notebook here: https://gist.github.com/tomc4yt/d2fb694247984b1f8e89cfd80aff8706 which shows the code and the results.

Here is a snippet of the model below...

```
class GaussWeights(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, shape, name='w'):
        return pm.Normal(
            name, mu=0, sd=.1,
            testval=np.random.normal(size=shape).astype(np.float32),
            shape=shape)


def build_ann(x, y, init):
    with pm.Model() as m:

        i = Input(tensor=x, shape=x.get_value().shape[1:])
        m = i
        m = Dense(4, init=init, activation='tanh')(m)
        m = Dense(1, init=init, activation='tanh')(m)

        sigma = pm.Normal('sigma', 0, 1, transform=None)
        out = pm.Normal('out', 
                         m, 1,
                         observed=y, transform=None)

    return out



 with pm.Model() as neural_network:
    likelihood = build_ann(input_var, target_var, GaussWeights())

#     v_params = pm.variational.advi(
#         n=300, learning_rate=.4
#     )
#     trace = pm.variational.sample_vp(v_params, draws=2000)
    start = pm.find_MAP(fmin=scipy.optimize.fmin_powell)
    step = pm.HamiltonianMC(scaling=start)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, step,   progressbar=True)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you think is going wrong? At first glance it looks to me like it has some trouble with the two modes but is fine otherwise. (also, you define `sigma` but don't use it anywhere...)

Comment: @aseyboldt I updated the question. The main issue is the trace is stuck at where the prior is initiated, take a look at the traceplot. When I move the prior the posterior moves to the same spot. The posterior predictive of the bayesian model in cell 59 is barely getting the sine wave, whereas the non-bayesian fit model gets it near perfect in cell 63. The sigma isn't used but shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Your model is saying that your measurements follow a normal distribution around the output from the network with std=1. You then sample 100 values per x value from the predictive posterior and take their median. Those samples have a variance of 1 + posterior_variance for each x-value. Their median than naturally still varies around the output from the network. It seems to me the model is doing exactly what your are telling it to do.

Comment: @aseyboldt. I'm only telling it the prior...which is what it's doing (as you point out). However the key part is that it's not sampling from the likelihood correctly. If the model was truly informed by the data then the median would match the sine curve as it does in cell 63 and sigma should not be as large as it is. Also take a look at cell 58...the trace clearly shows that the posterior for the parameters mimics the prior near perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model contains normal noise with a fixed std of 1:

```
out = pm.Normal('out', m, 1, observed=y)
```

but the dataset does not. It is only natural that the predictive posterior does not match the dataset, they were generated in a very different way. To make it more realistic you could add noise to your dataset, and then estimate sigma:

```
mu = pm.Deterministic('mu', m)
sigma = pm.HalfCauchy('sigma', beta=1)
pm.Normal('y', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=y)
```

What you are doing right now is similar to taking the output from the network and adding standard normal noise.

A couple of unrelated comments:

- `out` is not the likelihood, it is just the dataset again.
- If you use `HamiltonianMC` instead of `NUTS`, you need to set the step size and the integration time yourself. The defaults are not usually useful.
- Seems like keras changed in 2.0 and this way of combining pymc3 and keras does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: While this wasn't the solution that worked you did identify that the standard deviation was the issue which was technically true so I'll accept this. My priors were around the weights were poorly specified and when I put the appropriate hyperpriors according to Radford M Neal's work in this area I saw much better results. Specifially, my priors were constraining the search space and I needed to widen the standard dev of the weights